# How to make a field only editable by scanning in a bar code as values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if someone can point me into the right direction. I have a text input field, that I now need to update so a user can only "edit" through a scan gun to capture a bar code. My code so far was updated to prevent the user from adding data via keyboard but I am unsure how I can make it "editable" again via scan. During testing scanning was treated similar to key presses:

```
    $('#barCodeNum').keydown(function(){
        $('#barCodeNum').attr('readonly', true);
    });

    $('#barCodeNum').keyup(function(){
        $('#barCodeNum').attr('readonly', true);
        alert("You cannot manually edit this field. Please Scan the item.");
    });
```

What event should I be using, if there is any form of an event to capture the "action" of scanning? Or has anyone found another solution to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: Usually barcode scanners act as a keyboard input, which would prevent you from knowing whether its really a keyboard or not.

Comment: If you make it readonly... The codebar reader won't be able to fill the input. I suggest you to try `onkeydown` -> `return false;` to prevent any key from the keyboard... While the field still is opened to paste from the codebar reader (not a key effect).

Comment: Not sure what your use-case is, but have you ever bought anything from a supermarket where the barcode *doesn't scan*?  (cheese seems to be the worst...) - they manually read the digits and... type it in

Comment: I tired returning false; on keydown but it did not work for me. The scan was also treated the same. Could this also be any issue with how the scanner works/configured?

Comment: I Edited my answer with something for you to try... ;)

Comment: One solution (that is still a bit of a reach) would be to have a field that isn't visible to the user but that the barcode reader populates along with the field you are wanting it to populate. That second field could be populated with some random string by the barcode reader, and you verify that when new input is added to the main field, that the other field also got populated, and if it hasn't, the main field is cleared as not being from the barcode.

Comment: Orrrr... have the main field be hidden (so that only the barcode reader would populate it), and have the value of that field displayed to the user in another field that is read-only. The read-only field is the one the user sees (and is just the value from the hidden field), while the barcode actually populates the hidden field.

Comment: @Anthony: good idea!!! I will try to make a demo about the hidden field.

Comment: I removed my hidden field attempt... Because you need a way to "focus" the hidden field to use the codebar reader... So that's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Another idea... From [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49478/anthony)'s comment about an hidden field...
**But!** An hidden field just can't be focussed... And you need it to use the codebar reader.

So what about to place that "other" input outside the viewport (using CSS) instead of hiding it... Doing this, no one can focus it and just type in.

So in order to focus it, you will also need an "enable scan" button. The button will also start an interval to check for a value **inputed fast!** say... within 100ms... Then blur the field.

Here, there's only one delay to handle: The full scan minimum time. So that is easier...

No human can enter a complete code so fast.
Then you just need to validate that the code length is correct, based on your typical codes. If just one or two character are in... It's sure invalid.

**You'll have to adjust the "maxScanDelay"** by testing your scanner... 100ms may be too short. But make it as short as possible. ;)

Look below:

```js
var ScanCheck;
var maxScanDelay = 100;

$('#barCodeNum').on("keydown",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}); // End keydown on the visible

$('#barCodeNumHidden').on("input",function(e){
  $('#barCodeNum').val($(this).val());
}); // End keydown on the hidden

$("#scanEnable").on("click",function(){
  
  // Clear the fields
  $('#barCodeNum,#barCodeNumHidden').val("");
  
  $("#barCodeNumHidden").focus();
  $(this).text("Waiting for the code.");

  ScanCheck = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("interval");

    if($('#barCodeNumHidden').val()!=""){
      $("#barCodeNumHidden").blur();
      $("#scanEnable").text("Enable scan.");
      clearInterval(ScanCheck);
      console.log("interval stopped");
    }
  },maxScanDelay);
});
```

```css
#barCodeNumHidden{
  position:fixed;
  top:-100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="barCodeNum" readonly>
<input type="text" id="barCodeNumHidden">
<br>
<br>
<button id="scanEnable">Enable scan.</button>
```

---

**Typing speed solution**

If you make it readonly... The codebar reader won't be able to fill the input.

Since just `return false;` does not work...
I think I found a way to grab the characters typed FAST, like no human can, and get rid of the character typed more slowly.

I have no codebar reader to test that...
You will have two delays to adjust :

1. A threshold (key must be typed faster than this delay)
2. An "output" delay (to allow all characters to be collected before an output)

Here the code to try:

```
var string = "";
var timeout;
var lastEventTime = 0;

// ADJUST THOSE TWO!
var threshold = 35;
var outputDelay = 100;

$('#barCodeNum').on("keydown",function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  var codebarInput = $(this);

  // Get current time.
  var thisEventTime = Date.now();
  console.log(lastEventTime);
  console.log(thisEventTime);

  // Grab the character.
  string += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
  console.log(string);

  // If this event occurs sooner than the threshold delay, use the timeout to output the value when all characters are in string.
  if(lastEventTime+threshold > thisEventTime){
    console.log("OK");

    // Output the string after a delay.
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      codebarInput.val(string);
    },outputDelay);

  // If this event occurs after the threshold delay, clear string and input value.
  }else{
    console.log("NOT OK");

    codebarInput.val("");
    string = "";
    console.log("Key prevented.");
  }


  // Keep this event time.
  lastEventTime = thisEventTime;

}); // End keydown
```

From my tests on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/WdWgbd?editors=1011), a HOLDED down key works with a 35ms threshold... That seems to be the lowest, since 30ms block everything. With this threshold, even if I type as fast as I can, no single keys are passing. ;)

Comment: Man there's no way this could ever backfire.

Comment: Also, very clever. But I think the OP's needs are only going to be possible with a solution that will be prone to issues.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony. Well... I have no other idea. Let him try this and we'll see. ;)

Comment: This worked great buttt lol, I am guessing that the function fromCharCode that pulls the characters to form the string is pulling some hidden stuff from the barcode. Where there are upper cased letters, the field populates hidden chars. Trying to add a screenshot.

Comment: "fromCharc" ? I don't get it.

Comment: hmm i guess I cannot add screenshots. Anyways when the barcode is scanned, ex 2018_TEST_ITEM_00001, once scanned after each uppercase character it has a black diamond with a white question mark in the middle. These appears from the console where as the front end i see boxes of bits lol. I think its mocking me.

Comment: I see... Try replacing `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)` by `String.fromCharCode(e.which)`... Else, try my "other" solution ;)

Comment: Also.... We could try to determine what this character is... After `console.log(string);`, add `console.log(e.keycode);` We could filter it out of the "string". Tell me what keycode that can be...

Comment: I had to switch to e.which since when outputting the val for e.keycode it came up with undefined. E.which shows the evil doer as 16. But I also have underscores that are not showing as is, they are 173. So I got rid of the 16, the issues I have left are: underscores do not generate chars just blanks and for some reason the first letter/number wont populate, It get prevented

Comment: with some changes i got it all working for my purposes :D thanks @LouysPatriceBessette and others

Answer (score 1):

Usually barcode scanners act as a keyboard input, which would prevent you from knowing whether its a keyboard or a scanner.

One way to get around this is to check the timing between keypresses.  The barcode scanner inputs much faster than a human, and I believe you can modify this speed.

If the typing is slow enough you'll know its a keyboard.  If the typing is within some threshold you will know its the scanner.